# Check if all values in a dataframe is in a certain range, is there an attribute like `between` for dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, between

This is a bit awkward. I have a dataframe like below:

```
ticker          AAPL       AMD      BIDU     GOOGL      MSFT      NVDA  
Date                                                                     
2011-09-09  0.858191  0.726996  0.777005  0.738601  0.882434  0.844533   
2011-12-19  0.703769  0.789988  0.757444  0.866387  0.865608  0.817366   
2012-03-30  0.508363  0.737064  0.580451  0.332273  0.502175  0.582802   
2012-07-11  0.715340  0.754651  0.674592  0.680000  0.738280  0.664645   
2012-10-18  0.579068  0.342038  0.422278  0.441221  0.794282  0.571650   
2013-02-01  0.644426  0.440327  0.363183  0.571987  0.639081  0.508256   
2013-05-14  0.571758  0.342966  0.340528  0.681480  0.499203  0.612509   
2013-08-22  0.256618  0.439223  0.503821  0.632371  0.428107  0.496814   
2013-12-02  0.395739  0.281040  0.535051  0.457601  0.371708  0.555272   
...
```

I want to check if all values in `df` is in the range `[-1,1]`, I simply used

```
df.isin([-1,1])
```

which returned

```
ticker       AAPL    AMD   BIDU  GOOGL   MSFT   NVDA  
Date                                                                        
2011-09-09  False  False  False  False  False  False
2011-12-19  False  False  False  False  False  False
2012-03-30  False  False  False  False  False  False
2012-07-11  False  False  False  False  False  False
2012-10-18  False  False  False  False  False  False
2013-02-01  False  False  False  False  False  False
2013-05-14  False  False  False  False  False  False
2013-08-22  False  False  False  False  False  False
2013-12-02  False  False  False  False  False  False  
...
```

which is obviously wrong. But if I checked for a single column using `df["AAPL"].between(-1,1).any()`, it gave me `True`.

Why is that?
And is there a similar attribute like `between` for a dataframe? Because `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'between'`

Comment: `df.ge(0)&df.le(1)`?

Comment: Yes thank you. If I want to check if -1<=df<=1, shall I use `df.ge(-1)&df.le(1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`between` is a `Series` method only. Use math operator to do comparisons over a `DataFrame`:

```
>>> (-1 <= df) & (df <= 1)

ticker      AAPL   AMD  BIDU  GOOGL  MSFT  NVDA
Date
2011-09-09  True  True  True   True  True  True
2011-12-19  True  True  True   True  True  True
2012-03-30  True  True  True   True  True  True
2012-07-11  True  True  True   True  True  True
2012-10-18  True  True  True   True  True  True
2013-02-01  True  True  True   True  True  True
2013-05-14  True  True  True   True  True  True
2013-08-22  True  True  True   True  True  True
2013-12-02  True  True  True   True  True  True
```

After that, you can use `any` or `all` along an axis (or not) to select columns or rows.